# using XOR method 1 xor 1 will be equal to 1

Tags: vb.net

can somebody share me the code for 1 xor 1 will be equal to one  thank you so much for the response.
  Dim a As Integer = TextBox1.Text
        Dim b As Integer = TextBox2.Text

```
    Dim firstPattern As Integer
    firstPattern = (a Xor b)


    Console.WriteLine(firstPattern)
```

out put is :
textbox1 = 1
textbox2 = 10101101
result is : 10101100
what i want is : 10101101

Comment: That makes absolutely no sense whatsoever.  Either you want the result of an XOR operation or you don't.  If you do then use the `Xor` operator and that's what you'll get.  If you want an output different to what the `Xor` operator produces then you don't want the result of an XOR operation.  In that case, explain what you actually do want.  Telling us the output you want in one specific case is useless because you could innumerable algorithms to arrive at that output.  We need to know what the rules are that need to be applied in EVERY case.

Comment: thank you for the comment what i want is if 1 xor 0 = 1, 0 xor 1 = 1, 0 xor 0 = 0 and 1 xor 1 will be equal to one.

Comment: sorry im really a newbie in visual basic im really dizzy in steganography using lsb method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you said, you want Or, not Xor.

```
Dim firstPattern As Integer
firstPattern = (a Or b)
Console.WriteLine(firstPattern)
```

[Bitwise/Logical operators in VB.net](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vb.net/vb.net_logical_operators.htm)

Comment: can you give me a sample of OR code pls. this is my first time on visual basic